# nginx Connection timed out while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am using nginx + uwsgi over a flask app. In nginx settings the server block is having server_name *.mydomain.com; and location block for uwsgi is like

```
location /api/ {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass unix:///var/uwsgi/app.sock;
  .........
}
```

so the issue is I can access app.mydomain.com, but when i am trying app1.mydomain.com uwsgi log is not showing any request. nginx error log is showing

upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.166.94.231, server: *.mydomain.com, request: "GET /api/client/generic/ping HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///var/uwsgi/app.sock", host: "app1.mydomain.com

I have another test setup where all these settings are same and its working. Any pointers? When i restart uwsgi and nginx app1.mydomain.com works, until i load app.mydomain.com (initial load of app.mydomain.com fails, but if i keep on refreshing it loads then app1.mydomain.com raises 504 gateway timeout and log shows Connection timed out while reading response header from upstream).

Comment: Try increasing the timeout?

Comment: i tried, timeout is not the issue. it seems nothing appears in uwsgi log

Comment: @Sarun Did you ever solve this? We have same situation, exactly as you described.

Comment: It worked when I added single interpreter = true (google it for correct usage) in uwsgi settings. A newly added python library was causing the issue. Dont know whether this will  help your case.

Answer (score 2):

It worked when I added `single-interpreter = true` in `uwsgi.ini` settings.
A newly added python library was causing the issue.

Don't know whether this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue. uWSGI has "http", "http-socket" and "socket" options. When putting uWSGI behind a full webserver like Nginx, we should spawn uWSGI to natively speak the uWSGI protocol:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --wsgi-file foobar.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --stats 127.0.0.1:9191
```

More details from uwsgi documentation: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#putting-behind-a-full-webserver

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the uwsgi error logs and understanding what the problem is helped me. Issue was not related to Nginx configurations at all. My email host has changed and the code threw error while calling the send email code.